# Running lmer (Linear Mixed Effects Regression) in Python

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, lme4, mixed-models

I'd like to ask some questions about running `lmer` (Linear Mixed Effects Regression) models in Python.

Here are the two lines(or formulas) that I had run in the `lme4` package(in R). Is there any way I could fit the models as below in Python?

1. `TEST1 <- score ~ p1 + p2 + p3 + (1|v1) + (1|v2), data = df, control = lmerControl(boundary.tol = 1e-4, calc.derivs = FALSE))`
2. `TEST2 <- score ~ (1|v1) + (1|v2), data = df, control = lmerControl(boundary.tol = 1e-4, calc.derivs = FALSE))`

Comment: this might be a starting point https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/mixed_linear.html

Comment: Hi EJJ, thanks for your comment. I've tried to fit a model with statsmodel package, but found a memory error. It seems like I need some more efficient methods to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't required to actually run the model in Python, you could call and run the LMER models in R directly from your Python environment.

You could do this through [Rpy2](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/index.html) & rmagic or through [Pymer4](https://github.com/ejolly/pymer4). Both options allow you to use the lme4 package in R with the option to call them from a Python environment like jupyter notebooks.

I wrote a tutorial on how you could do this with examples that is available here: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-run-linear-mixed-effects-models-in-python-jupyter-notebooks-4f8079c4b589

As EJJ noted, there are implementations of LMER in Python such as in [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/mixed_linear.html) and [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Linear_Mixed_Effects_Models) but they appear less intuitive to use than the above method.